# Combining Spring, Quartz Scheduling and Hazelcast

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, hazelcast

I am trying to work out how to develop a reasonably scalable batch-processing framework for a webapp I am writing.

I am using Spring MVC for the webapp, with a custom DAO layer (to access the database a *UnitOfWork* instance is needed to be constructed from a *UnitOfWorkFactory* that is set as @Autowired and injected at runtime by Spring).

I am using the Spring Scheduler annotations (@Scheduled) to schedule tasks, however I want these tasks to run on different machines in my cluster. Each batch job should be picked up by one of the cluster machines and then executed.

[Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com) seemed like a natural fit for this as the [Distributed Execution](http://hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/single_html/#DistributedExecution) design appeared really simple and elegant for this purpose.

I am running into a problem that doesn't seem to be covered by the documentation. I have read the documentation about [Spring Integration](http://hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/single_html/#SpringIntegration) however this seems focused at how to configure Hazelcast using Spring (which I have done already).

When the scheduler indicates that the task is to start I want to create a new instance of the task (a *Callable* instance) and submit it to the *DistributedExecutor*. When a cluster machine receives the task to run I need the Spring container on the cluster machine to inject the *UnitOfWorkFactory* instance into the batch task before the task attempts to execute it. Each of the clusters starts with Spring and will have the *UnitOfWorkFactory* already instantiated with the correct details, the problem is with getting the *UnitOfWorkFactory* instance injected into my task.

Does anybody know how I can configure my application so that Hazelcast can have the *UnitOfWorkFactory* injected automatically when a *Callable* is started? I have tried marking the *Callable* as Serializable and *ApplicationContextAware* but I still get *NullPointerException* when trying to run the task.

I could access the ApplicationContext directly, however I would rather not as it will restrict the testability of my tasks and introduce a hard-dependency on Spring for my batch jobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**By version 2.1** Hazelcast can inject Spring context and/or Spring beans into Hazelcast managed objects.

If you configure Hazelcast using Hazelcast Spring configuration and annotate a bean using `@SpringAware`, Hazelcast will ask Spring to inject dependencies of that bean.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.1.xsd">
   <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
      <hz:config>
         <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
         <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false" />
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>10.10.1.2, 10.10.1.3</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
         </hz:network>
         ...
      </hz:config>
   </hz:hazelcast>

   <bean id="someBean" class="com.hazelcast.examples.spring.SomeBean" 
          scope="singleton" />
   ...
</beans>
```

---

```
@SpringAware 
public class SomeTask implements Callable<Long>, ApplicationContextAware, Serializable {
   private transient ApplicationContext context;
   private transient SomeBean someBean;

   public Long call() throws Exception {
     return someBean.value;
   }

   public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext)
       throws BeansException {
      context = applicationContext;
   }

   @Autowired
   public void setSomeBean(final SomeBean someBean) {
      this.someBean = someBean;
   }
}
```

---

> **For older versions than 2.1:**

Versions before 2.1 of Hazelcast are not Spring aware, so it is not possible to inject Spring context or any Spring bean into a Hazelcast managed object for pre-2.1 versions.

There is a post asking about this feature on Hazelcast group.

[Hazelcast / Dependency injection for Callable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/0cPDsAwcUcs)

As you may already know and suggested in Hazelcast group you can access Spring ApplicationContext using;

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context = null;

    public synchronized void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
        if(context == null) {
            context = applicationContext;
        }
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String name) {
        return (T) context.getBean(name);
    }
}  

class MyCallable implements Callable {
    ....
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        SomeServiceBean bean = ApplicationContextProvider.getBean("serviceBean");
        ....
    }
}
```